# r - calculate using next non-na value in data frame column

Tags: r, lag, lead

I have some data in a dataframe, and I would like to calculate the percentage change between the `month` value.  The problem is I have `NA` in some entries and it throws of the calculation.

```
       irm     code        price    pct.change
1  201807 511130F075A04      4.6600   2.192982
2  201806 511130F075A04      4.5600   1.333333
3  201805 511130F075A04      4.5000 -13.461538
4  201804 511130F075A04      5.2000         NA
5  201803 511130F075A04          NA         NA
6  201802 511130F075A04      4.9100   1.867220
7  201801 511130F075A04      4.8200  -5.304519
8  201712 511130F075A04      5.0900   2.414487
9  201711 511130F075A04      4.9700  -3.307393
10 201710 511130F075A04      5.1400         NA
11 201709 511130F075A04          NA         NA
12 201708 511130F075A04      5.2900   2.918288
13 201707 511130F075A04      5.1400  66.553255
14 201706 511130F075A04      3.0861 -10.664351
15 201705 511130F075A04      3.4545  -7.241824
```

The problem is in row 4 and row 10 in the `pct.change` column.  They are `NA` but I would like them to be calculated using the latest value of `price` that is not`NA`.  The desired output would be (see rows 4 and 10):

```
       irm     code        price    pct.change
1  201807 511130F075A04      4.6600   2.192982
2  201806 511130F075A04      4.5600   1.333333
3  201805 511130F075A04      4.5000 -13.461538
**4  201804 511130F075A04      5.2000   5.906314**
5  201803 511130F075A04          NA         NA
6  201802 511130F075A04      4.9100   1.867220
7  201801 511130F075A04      4.8200  -5.304519
8  201712 511130F075A04      5.0900   2.414487
9  201711 511130F075A04      4.9700  -3.307393
**10 201710 511130F075A04      5.1400  -2.835539**
11 201709 511130F075A04          NA         NA
12 201708 511130F075A04      5.2900   2.918288
13 201707 511130F075A04      5.1400  66.553255
14 201706 511130F075A04      3.0861 -10.664351
15 201705 511130F075A04      3.4545  -7.241824
```

I had tried the standard `(x/lead(x) - 1)*100` and several variations using `(x/lag(which(!is.na(lead(x))` but I seem to be missing something.  Is there a straightforward way to do it in `base` or even `dplyr`?  **I don't want to replace the NAs, I want to keep them.**

Comment: `df$pct.change[!is.na(df$price)] <- with(df[!is.na(df$price),], 
                                        (price/dplyr::lead(price) - 1) * 100)`

Comment: I like this but when I use it on my full `data.frame` I get the following warning:  `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.  It DOES work really well in the example, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@LAP's comment is probably the best way to do it. The syntax is a little better with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[!is.na(price), pct.change := 100*(price/shift(price, type = 'lead') - 1)]

#        irm          code  price pct.change
#  1: 201807 511130F075A04 4.6600   2.192982
#  2: 201806 511130F075A04 4.5600   1.333333
#  3: 201805 511130F075A04 4.5000 -13.461538
#  4: 201804 511130F075A04 5.2000   5.906314
#  5: 201803 511130F075A04     NA         NA
#  6: 201802 511130F075A04 4.9100   1.867220
#  7: 201801 511130F075A04 4.8200  -5.304519
#  8: 201712 511130F075A04 5.0900   2.414487
#  9: 201711 511130F075A04 4.9700  -3.307393
# 10: 201710 511130F075A04 5.1400  -2.835539
# 11: 201709 511130F075A04     NA         NA
# 12: 201708 511130F075A04 5.2900   2.918288
# 13: 201707 511130F075A04 5.1400  66.553255
# 14: 201706 511130F075A04 3.0861 -10.664351
# 15: 201705 511130F075A04 3.4545         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

in Base R you can decide to replace:

```
 a = which(is.na(df$price))-1
 transform(df,pct.change=replace(pct.change,a,100*(price[a]/price[a+2]-1)))
      irm          code  price pct.change
1  201807 511130F075A04 4.6600   2.192982
2  201806 511130F075A04 4.5600   1.333333
3  201805 511130F075A04 4.5000 -13.461538
4  201804 511130F075A04 5.2000   5.906314
5  201803 511130F075A04     NA         NA
6  201802 511130F075A04 4.9100   1.867220
7  201801 511130F075A04 4.8200  -5.304519
8  201712 511130F075A04 5.0900   2.414487
9  201711 511130F075A04 4.9700  -3.307393
10 201710 511130F075A04 5.1400  -2.835539
11 201709 511130F075A04     NA         NA
12 201708 511130F075A04 5.2900   2.918288
13 201707 511130F075A04 5.1400  66.553255
14 201706 511130F075A04 3.0861 -10.664351
15 201705 511130F075A04 3.4545  -7.241824
```

Comment: this is pretty clever.  but what if there are 2 `NA` in consecutive rows?

Comment: @jvalenti even the answer accepted will face the same issue. You will have to determine a way for that

Comment: No, the row argument in the `data.table` syntax used specifies that the calculations focus on rows where `price != NA`, so it just shifts to the next value in the column that meets that condition.